# Device mapping in Internet Arcade

Tags: archive.org

Using [Internet Arcade](https://archive.org/details/internetarcade), The Internet Archive's online MAME emulator,  how can I access the device mapping menu so that I can enable alternate controls? In particular, I am looking to enable mouse input.

In other MAME platforms, [this is done prior to opening a game](https://bytesnbits.co.uk/mame-mouse-control/). Is this possible in browser/Javascript versions of MAME?

Comment: According to the Internet Arcade link, it uses JSMAME, part of the JSMESS software package.

Answer (score 2):

From [Alexander Pruss's blog post](https://alexanderpruss.blogspot.com/2023/02/two-tweaks-for-internet-arcade-games-on.html), edited to only provide mouse support:

To add mouse support, first, go to a game, but don't click the start button.

Then put the following into the URL bar and press enter:

`javascript:MAMELoader.extraArgs=(z)=>({extra_mame_args:['-mouse']});AJS.emulate()`

(Note that Chrome will not let you past the "javascript:" prefix into the URL bar. You can copy and paste the rest, but you have to type "javascript:" manually.) The game will start, and the mouse will be enabled. You can [add other MAME options](https://docs.mamedev.org/commandline/commandline-all.html) if you like.

You can also turn this into a bookmarklet by pasting the same line into the URL field of a bookmark.

Comment: Drag the link to the bookmark bar doesn't work for me, very likely because the link includes `https://`. Rel. [Add a bookmarklet in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/q/279107/1794161). I don't think that the Stacks Editor allows adding links having other protocols than `http://` and `https://`. If you want to confirm this, I suggest you ask on [meta.se].

Comment: I just edited the answer to direct people to instead create their own bookmarklet.